# Can you buy a Series 2 Apple Watch body-only?

Tags: apple-watch

I already own, and still use my original release Apple Watch, released Spring 2015. I love the bands that I own and have no need nor interest in another one.

Apple's Gallery and Pre-Order page lists the body and bands together, is it possible to buy a Series 2 Watch Body only, and forego the band?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-you-buy-an-Apple-Watch-without-a-watch-band

Comment: The vast majority of those answers are from 2015, the one posted 6 days ago as of this writing comes before Apple's September 7th announcement and reveal of Series 2. The link technically doesn't answer the question. It makes no sense to buy the first watch without a band, but upgrading to a Series 2 only requires the body, not a whole new band.

Comment: I see your point and agree, but honestly I have no idea. I know this is bad form, but maybe [chat with Apple](https://aoschat.apple.com/Chat/getCustomerDetails.do)? Often they can help you do something the website itself doesn't offer.

Comment: I wasn't planning on engaging them directly until the 16th, but it is possible that someone has a verified source from an interview, news source, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Watch bands fit the watch based on its size, either 38MM or 42MM, and are interchangeable between both series, however at the present time Apple only sells the Apple Watch, either series, with a band. There is no SKU available in the computer to order without a band.  This information is current as of this moment having just contacted Apple sales directly, at the local Apple Store, seeking to purchase an Apple Watch without a band.

Comment: And is still the case, so the answer is no, you cannot buy a Series 2, sans band.